# ORA-00920 Invalid Relational operator *Where Clause Error Help*

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to see what operator is wrong in this huge query. It seems that an operator is wrong in all this. Any expert can help me out? Thanks everyone for helping me out

```
INSERT
    INTO FORUORH
      (
        FORUORH_USER_ID_ENTERED,
        FORUORH_COAS_CODE,
        FORUORH_ORGN_CODE,
        FORUORH_ACCESS_IND,
        FORUORH_ACTIVITY_DATE,
        FORUORH_USER_ID,
        FORUORH_END_DATE,
        FORUORH_WBUD_ACCESS_IND
      )
    SELECT FORUSOR_USER_ID_ENTERED,
      FORUSOR_COAS_CODE,
      FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE,
      FORUSOR_ACCESS_IND,
      FORUSOR_ACTIVITY_DATE,
      FORUSOR_USER_ID,
      SYSDATE,
      FORUSOR_WBUD_ACCESS_IND
    FROM FORUSOR
    WHERE FORUSOR_USER_ID_ENTERED                 = :KEY_BLOCK_USER_ID
    AND ((FORUSOR_COAS_CODE, FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE)) IN (
      (SELECT FORUSOR_COAS_CODE,
        FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE
      FROM FORUSOR
      WHERE FORUSOR_COAS_CODE LIKE NVL(:KEY_BLOCK_INCLUDE_COAS_CODE, '%')
      AND FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE LIKE NVL(:KEY_BLOCK_INCLUDE_ORGN_CODE, '%')
      AND FORUSOR_USER_ID_ENTERED = :KEY_BLOCK_USER_ID
      MINUS
      SELECT FORUSOR_COAS_CODE,
        FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE
      FROM FORUSOR
      WHERE FORUSOR_COAS_CODE LIKE NVL(:KEY_BLOCK_EXCLUDE_COAS_CODE, '%')
      AND FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE LIKE NVL(:KEY_BLOCK_EXCLUDE_ORGN_CODE, '#')
      AND FORUSOR_USER_ID_ENTERED = :KEY_BLOCK_USER_ID
      )) ";
```

Comment: Have you tested individual sub queriee or tried removing where conditions to narrow down where the error is originating from?

Comment: Tried to copy paste into sql developer and he underlined my "IN" operator with red color (syntax error) suggesting me other stuff to put

Comment: For problems like that an editor which highlights matching brackets is the best debugging tool.

Answer (score 1):

`((FORUSOR_COAS_CODE, FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE))` vector should be `(FORUSOR_COAS_CODE, FORUSOR_ORGN_CODE)`

Comment: Thank you so much!
Highly appreciated.